# Hide/show urls in form view in openerp

Tags: forms, openerp-7

I am trying to put a link to download docs files in form view. I already have the links and I made a custom web controller that actually does the download but the problem is that they present in every part of the view. I want it to appear based on specific condition where the state field of an applicant is set to a specific value similar to buttons in form view.

Bellow is an example of a button that appears based on the state condition:

```
<button name="action_open_agreement_form" type="object" string="P020 Declaration and undertaking" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','!=','done')]}"/>
```

this allows me to show a button if the state of the applicant is not done.

The link I have is as bellow in the xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_sefarer_applicant_form">
    <field name="name">Jobs - Recruitment Form</field>
<field name="model">seafarer.applicant</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Jobs - Recruitment Form" version="7.0">
        ...
        <sheet>
            ......
    <div class="oe_right oe_button_box">
                ....
                <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/sc/some_html?id=P014-'+$('.seafarer_id span').text(), '_blank')" class="applicant_docs_forms"  id="P014">P014 Drug/Alcohol Delcaration</a>
                .....
            </div>
        </sheet>
     .....
```

I need to use something like attrs but it is not working, I also tried to use javascript with on window load or  document ready but that's not working too. I also tried desperate things like having a button with attrs with the condition and having a onclick action on it that clicks the link and having the link hidden but that didn't work as well.

I am pretty desperate and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an entire `div` invisible based on group membership or field content (such as `state`), or you can put the links in fields, and make those invisible using the same criteria.